# How can I make lines of a Qt table bold with PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In the PyQt creator I made a 9*9 Table looking like this: 
[image]
In that table I want to make every third line separating the rows and every third line separating columns and the the border lines bold. Is that possible to do in PyQt?
If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegate for that:

```
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        if ((1+index.row()) % 3 == 0): # Every third row
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3))
            painter.drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight())

        if ((1+index.column()) % 3 == 0): # Every third column
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3))
            painter.drawLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    v = QTableView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(9, 9)
    v.setModel(model)
    v.show()
    v.setItemDelegate(Delegate(v))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In my file I cant use the functions QStyledItemDelegate, QPen and Qt.red. Do I need to import anything special for that?

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate`
`from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen`
`from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt`