# Is it possible to disable the highlighting effect on a selected cell in a QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In this example, I have a grid with cells that can be colored and uncolored.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 750, 750)

        self.rows=60
        self.columns=50
        self.tableWidget=QTableWidget(self.rows, self.columns)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().hide()
        
        self.activated={}
        self.item={}
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.columns):
                self.activated[r,c]=False
                self.item[r,c]=QTableWidgetItem()
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r,c,self.item[r,c])

        self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        #self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        #self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("""QTableView:item:selected{selection-background-color: rgb(100,100,150);}""")
        #self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("""QTableView:item:selected{selection-background-color: transparent;}""")
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.dothing)
        self.tableWidget.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.dothing)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)
    
    def dothing(self,r,c):
        if self.activated[r,c]: 
            self.activated[r,c]=False
            self.item[r,c].setBackground(QColor(255,255,255))

        else: 
            for column in range(60):
                self.activated[column]=False
                self.item[column,c].setBackground(QColor(255,255,255))
            self.activated[r,c]=True
            self.item[r,c].setBackground(QColor(100,100,150))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

However, as you might notice from running the code, the colored-in color is obscured by the highlight color, as a result of selection.
Without changing the selection mode (ie. `self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)`), or adjusting the stylesheet, is it possible for me to completely disable/bypass the highlight color paint event?

I must note that it is important that the selection mode and stylesheets aren't adjusted, as I intend on using the selection range to create a length of colored cells in a single row at once. If selection is disabled, then this cannot happen at all, and if the stylesheet is edited, then it would show multiple rows of cells being highlighted rather than just one row.

Hence, these solutions from previous SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635018/how-can-i-make-lines-of-a-qt-table-bold-with-pyqt) don't really work for me.

Comment: Question: if the selection is not *visible*, how can the user know what are the selected items?

Comment: @musicamante There is no point to the selected items; the color-change on click would that the cell is selected.  I basically only want to keep it so that I can make use of the selection range, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: use an [item delegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details).

Just subclass a [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and reimplement its [`initStyleOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) in order to *override* the selected state of the item, so that it will be painted just using the default background color:

```py
class DeselectedDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        opt.state &= ~QStyle.State_Selected


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(
            DeselectedDelegate(self.tableWidget))
```

Note that setting the backgrounds of all the items in the column is not very effective, especially if it's only for display reasons and always consistent as your code shows (not to mention that you used the name `column` that actually refers to a *row*).

A more appropriate solution could just use the `self.activated` dictionary and keep the same reference in the delegate. By further implementing the above, you could just change the [`backgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#backgroundBrush-var) of the style option whenever the row/column reference is `True` in the dict, and ensure that all items are repainted<sup>[1]</sup>:

```py
class DeselectedDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, activated):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.activated = activated

    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        opt.state &= ~QStyle.State_Selected
        if self.activated[index.row(), index.column()]:
            opt.backgroundBrush = QColor(100,100,150)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(
            DeselectedDelegate(self.tableWidget, self.activated))
        # note that added argument

    def dothing(self, row, column):
        active = not self.activated[row, column]
        self.activated[row, column] = active
        if active:
            for r in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                if r != row:
                    self.activated[r, column] = False
        self.tableWidget.viewport().update()
```

<sup>[1] Note that I specifically called the `viewport.update()`, because item views, as all Qt scroll areas paint their contents in their *viewport* (calling `self.tableWidget.update()` would have no result); while repainting the whole viewport might not seem very optimal, it's certainly better than setting the background of **all** items in the same column (including those that are not currently shown). It's worth noticing that it *is* possible to update only a *region* of the viewport (in your case, that referring to the *column* interested by the value changes), but, unless extremely complex painting is required on each item (for instance, custom pixmaps), that solution is not worth it.</sup>

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. It's really cool how you utilized the flags; I saw this mentioned in a Qt forum post earlier, but wasn't sure how to use it. I also missed the column row confusion in my code completely, haha.

Comment: @rllysleepy You're welcome! About the flag usage, it's basic binary operations. Qt (just like most toolkits/modules/etc) uses `OR` flags *a lot* in order to use a single "property" as a reference that could contain many basic values related to the same aspects. The `~` (NOT) operator "negates" the value, and when used along with `&=` (AND) assignment it *clears* the bit(s) related to the given flag. `x = 7;x &= ~2` results in x being 5. How? `2` is binary `10`, its negation *theoretically* is `01`, but it's actually `1[...]101` (the length depends on the maximum bit size of integers for the ->

Comment: -> current system: a 64b system normally has a maximum bit length of 63 bits for integers, allowing negatives), so `~2` is actually made of 61 "ones", a "zero" and a further "one". The AND operator (requiring *left* and *right* side values) always returns only the bits that at *both sides* are equal (the resulting bit is 1 if both values have 1 at the same position). For example: `1 & 2` returns 0, because 1 (`01`) and 2 (`10`) both have inconsistent bits at their positions; `3 & 2` gives 2, since 3 (`11`) and 2 only have the second bit in common, giving a binary `10`, which is 2 in integer.->

Comment: -> Using the AND *compound operator* (`&=`) and the NOT together *clears* the given bit(s) of the second one: 7 is `0[…]111`, the negation of 2 is `1[…]101` (the only `1` bit of `10` becomes `0`, all the other become `1`), which results in `0[…]101`, aka 5. Flags work in the same way: the `option.state` is an OR based ([as per documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StateFlag-enum)) combination of QStyle.StateFlags, meaning that it can use bin operators as explained above. See this [related post](//stackoverflow.com/q/47981) and [this tutorial](//realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/).

Comment: Oh wow, that's surprisingly complex for something I thought would be much easier. I never thought I'd be learning bitwise operations for GUI stuff. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @rllysleepy Yeah, it seems terribly complex: I know, I felt the same at first. But, believe me, once you begin to understand binary operations, you'll see their wonderful simplicity. Let me clarify. Using `~y` is like "tell me *everything you know* that is **`NOT`** related to `y`". Doing `x &= z` is like saying "ok, tell me everything that is only related to `x` **`AND`** `z`". Finally, with both operators: `x &= ~y` means "tell me everything you know about `x` **`AND`** is only related to anything you know that is **`NOT`** about `y`". Get it? :-)

Comment: Let's take a slightly different example, using a basic "realm" of 4 bits (the maximum integer is 15, `b1111`). Consider `x` as 6 (`0110`), `y` as 10 (`1010`). Doing `x &= y` means that only the common "ones" at each bit position are actually `1`: `0111 AND 1010` only gives the second to last bit as `1`, so `0111 & 1010` results in `0010` (in fact, integer 2). Now, negating `y` (`1010`) results in `0101` (integer 5). Using the `&` operator returns only the bits that are common on both sides: `x` is `0110`, `NOT y` is `0101`, the only common bit is the third (`0100`): `6 & ~10` equals `4`.

Comment: Breaking it down into sentences like that makes it so much clearer, thank you. That's actually such an excellent way to think of these operators, I think I'll try applying that kind of thinking more in the future.

Comment: Note that `6 & ~10` is *not* the same as `10 & ~6`: the negation of `10` (`1010`) is `0101`, the negation of 6 (`0110`) is `1001`: while `6 & ~10` makes 4 (`0100`), `10 & ~6` makes 8 (because `1010` **`AND`** `1001` only makes `1000`, since only the fourth bit is a common "one"). I hope this really helps... Good luck! :-)